# Rabbitmq installation and admin user creation

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to install rabbitmq using a batch file on windows .It installs properly but when i try to create user as administrator ,it executes only first command and then stops.I also tried using "--quiet" argument. Following is my batch file :

cd ../rabbitmq

rabbitmq-server-3.8.3.exe /S /D=%CD%

cd rabbitmq_server-3.8.3/sbin

Please suggest a suitable solution.
rabbitmqctl --quiet add_user test test -> (stops here .doesnt execute next commands)

rabbitmqctl --quiet set_user_tags test administrator

rabbitmqctl --quiet set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"

Please suggest a suitable solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As we are calling a bat file from another bat file we need to add "CALL" befor each statement.For eg.
CALL rabbitmqctl --quiet add_user test test
CALL rabbitmqctl --quiet set_user_tags test administrator